# cant load .styl with webpack override

Tags: reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, stylus-loader

I am using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and want to use .styl as css.
The issue that I tried to add some plugin in order to use .styl inside my components with react.

file name:config-overrides.js

```
var stylus_plugin = require('stylus_plugin');

    module.exports = function override(config, env) {
        config.plugins = [
            new stylusLoader.OptionsPlugin({
                default: {
                  use: [stylus_plugin()],
                },
              }),
```

the eror that I am getting

> Error: Cannot find module 'stylus_plugin''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find a great plugin that doing it

> npm install --save-dev react-app-rewire-stylus-modules